# Python dispatching attribute access to embeded object

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I have a class similar to this:

```
class C(object):

    _use_obj = 'attr1 attr2'.split()

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    # class definition continues here defining a few attributes and methods
```

I want to be able to access the attributes of `obj` via `C` with certain rules.

`c.this` should return:

1. `obj.this` if `this` is in `C._use_obj`
2. `C.this` if `this` is defined in `C`
3. `obj.this` if `this` is not defined in `C`

`this` can be an attribute (class or instance), a property or a method. And I do not know what is `myobj` before hand. In the absence of rule 1, I think I can do it with `__getattr__`. But with rule 1 it is not clear to me as I need to intercept all attribute access.

Comment: I don't see why you think rule 1 means you can't use `__getattr__`.  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @BrenBarn Because `__getatrr__` will not be called if `this` is defined in `C`

Comment: It might help to update your example so that it actually shows the problem.  Your example `C` doesn't have any attributes that overlap with those defined in `_use_obj`.  In any case, you could still use `__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept *all* attribute access with [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), but you need to be careful to hand control over to the overridden method if you don't have a matching attribute. **All** attribute access is handled by this method, you need to be careful not to end up in an infinite recursive loop:

```
class C(object):
    _use_obj = 'attr1 attr2'.split()

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # setup, make it easier to get attributes we need
        get = super(C, self).__getattribute__
        use_obj = get('_use_obj')
        obj = get('obj')

        if name in use_obj:
            # rule 1, attribute is specifically listed
            return getattr(obj, name)
        try:
            # rule 2, try attribute on self
            return get(name)
        except AttributeError:
            # rule 3, fall back to self.obj
            return getattr(obj, name)
```